# Redirect mail.example.com to example.com/webmail

Tags: email, .htaccess, redirect

Is there any way to redirect HTTP requests that go to `mail.example.com` (which is my mail server) to go to the webmail interface, `example.com/webmail`? I've tried to create a subdomain called `mail.example.com`, but it conflicts with my mail server and cPanel won't allow me to create it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are bunch of sub-domains CPanel creates for each domain. for example if you register `example.com` , CPanel creates:

- `ftp.example.com`
- `mail.example.com`
- `cpanel.example.com`
- `vhm.example.com`

by default all these sub-domains point at current server, so If you want to use FTP, there is no difference between `example.com` or `ftp.example.com`. Both will work.

So, for your mail sub-domain you can set a document root for it(e.g your webmail interface directory). and because SMTP and POP3 are on diffrent ports, it will work fine with mail clients like Thunderbird.

For setting document root to `mail.example.com` login to your CPanel and go to Advanced DNS editing part and delete `mail.example.com`. Then create sub-domain with this name.
You can set document root to webmail interface  or redirect users to `example.com/webmail`.
that's your call.

Note: I haven't tested it my self but I tested such thing for FTP. Let me know if it fails.